# Методы списков С#

Tags: c#, методы

Необходимо из списка удалить все элементы с непарными индексами.
Мое решение (весьма колхозное) выглядит так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> lists = new List<int>()
        {
            0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                lists.Remove(lists[i]);
                lists.Insert(i, 0);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lists[i] == 0)
            {
                lists.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lists[i]);
        }
    }
```

Список создан учебный, потом будет ввод.
Цифры в порядке возрастания сделаны для удобства.

Вопрос: как оптимизировать код и сделать его более удобным для чтения?
(Метод для отбора элементов в с#, в Java - RemoveIf(нужен аналог)).

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях идут с конца. Дабы не менять индекс следующего за ним элемента

Comment: `var result = lists.Where((_, i) => i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Опять что ли имелись в виду нечётные индексы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так посмотрите

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> lists = new List<int>()
    {
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    };
        for (int i = lists.Count - 1 ; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                lists.Remove(lists[i]);
                //lists.RemoveAt(i); по вашему усмотрению
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lists[i]);
        }
    }
```

А по хорошему не заморачивайтесь с циклами и изучайте Linq

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> lists = new List<int>()
        {
            0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
        };

        lists.Where((number, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
```